# Symfony authentification : bad credentials

Tags: symfony, authentication

I created an authentification form and when I try to log on I get the error "Invalid credentials".
I checked with error.messageKey and the problem does not come from the username, so the problem must come from the password.

I looked everywhere and I don't see what's wrong.
Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

```
security:
    hide_user_not_found: false
    encoders:
        App\Entity\Utilisateur:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 5

    providers:
        in_memory: { memory: ~ }

        in_database:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Utilisateur
                property: mail

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
             anonymous: true

            provider: in_database

            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                default_target_path: home
```

and login.twig

```
                <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group" id="formMail">
                        <label for="email">Email :</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="dupont@gmail.com" required name="_username">
                        <span class="" id="spanMail"></span>
                        <span class="" id="spanErrMail"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" id="formMdp">
                        <label for="pwd">Mot de passe :</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="******" required name="_password">
                        <span class="" id="spanMdp"></span>
                        <span class="" id="spanErrMdp"></span>
                    </div>
```

User entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UtilisateurRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 * fields={"mail"},
 * message="Adresse mail déjà utilisée")
 */
 class Utilisateur implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $nom;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $prenom;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\Email(
 *     message = "L'e-mail {{ value }} n'est pas valide ")
 */
private $mail;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\Length(min="5", minMessage="Le mot de passe doit faire au moins 5 caractères")
 */
private $mdp;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getNom(): ?string
{
    return $this->nom;
}

public function setNom(string $nom): self
{
    $this->nom = $nom;

    return $this;
}

public function getPrenom(): ?string
{
    return $this->prenom;
}

public function setPrenom(string $prenom): self
{
    $this->prenom = $prenom;

    return $this;
}

public function getMail(): ?string
{
    return $this->mail;
}

public function setMail(string $mail): self
{
    $this->mail = $mail;

    return $this;
}

public function getMdp(): ?string
{
    return $this->mdp;
}

public function setMdp(string $mdp): self
{
    $this->mdp = $mdp;

    return $this;
}

public function getPassword(){}
public function getUsername(){
    return $this->mail;
}
public function eraseCredentials(){}
public function getSalt(){
    return '';
}
public function getRoles()
{
    return ['ROLE_USER'];
}
}
```

Comment: What is the user entity?

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Ca you check if the user can be actually fetched from the dB? If the repository does not return any result or throw an exception the error massage is the same.

Comment: If I enter a wrong username I have the error "username not found", so I guess the user is fetched from the dB

Comment: You can test that from the controller, just to fetch via the method in the user repository.

Comment: I have tested from the controller to find the user via its email and it is working. I put in the placeholder the password : it shows the crypted password.I suppose the problem is with the encryption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mystake.
I was using my own functions names to get the email and password.

I was supposed to implement getUsername() and getPassword().

```
public function getMdp(): ?string
{
    return $this->mdp;
}

public function setMdp(string $mdp): self
{
    $this->mdp = $mdp;

    return $this;
}

public function getPassword(){
    return $this->mdp;
}

public function getUsername(){
    return $this->mail;
}
```

Comment: Off-topic but the [argon2i](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-argon2i-configuration) encoder is now recommended.